# Bootstrap, cannot move navbar elements to the far left

Tags: html, css

I would like the navbar elements to start from the edges. Kinda like how [amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk) does it. I am using the bootstrap basic theme, and it has a collapsible navbar div which I think is stopping me from moving them, however I am not sure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SheetPal</title>

    <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
    body {  
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #2555a3; border-bottom: none;" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SheetPal</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Hours</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            User
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Support</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `.container-fluid` to obtain your needs. please check the code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #2555a3; border-bottom: none;" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SheetPal</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Hours</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        User
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```